# ghs.google.com timing out

Tags: google-app-engine, timeout

The former Google Group for this recommends posting here.

I run a bunch of websites on google apps for your domain and GAE.

Currently they are all down as gas.google.com is timing out.

> ping ghs.google.com
>   PING ghs.l.google.com (74.125.31.121): 56 data bytes
>   Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
>   Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
>   Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
>   Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
>   Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
>   Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
>   Request timeout for icmp_seq 6

Hopefully google is aware and investigating.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

Must be just you... Perhaps a trace route would yield better info.

```
Pinging ghs.l.google.com [74.125.129.121] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 74.125.129.121: bytes=32 time=49ms TTL=47
Reply from 74.125.129.121: bytes=32 time=49ms TTL=47
Reply from 74.125.129.121: bytes=32 time=69ms TTL=47
Reply from 74.125.129.121: bytes=32 time=50ms TTL=47

Ping statistics for 74.125.129.121:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
```

Answer (score 0):

Hן Matt

You can try to use PageSpeed and change the DNS CNAME to pagespeed.googlehosted.com

By the way, this CNAME is working even if you do not use PageSpeed.